# convert ini read value(string) to int

Tags: c#, converters, ini

I was surprised that C# doesn't support ini handle but of course i knew that it wouldn't be so hard to do so a simple search gave me this small and easy class to handle simple ini files
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C

iniReadValue returns a string and i want to convert it to integer.
I though that a Convert.ToInt32 would work but it doesn so this wont work

```
int keyclosewindows = Convert.ToInt32(ini.IniReadValue("Key info", "CloseWindows"));
```

The ini read returns me an integer stored in a string

```
ini.IniReadValue("Key info", "CloseWindows") //= "1"
```

I know this is a silly question but unfortunately i can not come up with a solution

Error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: @L.B Will give the same issue as Convert.ToInt32

Comment: gives same issue as Convert.ToInt32

Comment: @L.B I suspect this is actually not the same as the other question, in that I'm guessing that the string includes `"` here (which is why it's failing).  The OP already demonstrated knowledge of how to do a conversion, but it's not working *in this case*.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what is the error message?

Comment: This is the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
i will edit 1st post

Comment: So the value read from your file is not a valid integer value. At this point probably the answer below is pointing to the right direction. You have some character that cannot be parsed as an integer

Comment: FYI, .ini files are rarely used these days - we use XML instead.

Comment: I am using ini to be able to allow users to makes easy changes...
@Steve the value is "1".
It happens the same if i set hexes. If the value is "0x31" it will throw me the same error

Comment: I have downloaded the code from your link and created a simple INI file with the values used by you. (No quotes around the 1) and it works perfectly. Perhaps you could paste also that part of the INI file.

Comment: No way to guess what the problem is without data - please show value of `ini.IniReadValue("Key info", "CloseWindows")` call.

Comment: I could reproduce the error if I mispell the the Section value. In that case no section is found and the return is an empty string that cannot be converted

Comment: In case you or anyone else reading this is interested, I've built an small library for parsing ini files easily: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser is open source (MIT) and written completely in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of `IniReadValue` includes the quotation marks, you'll need to trim them off before converting to an integer:

```
var temp = ini.IniReadValue("Key info", "CloseWindows").Trim('\"');
int keyclosewindows = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
```

Otherwise, the issue is that the ini key either doesn't exist, or is in a format that isn't an integer.

Comment: +1 "includes the parentheses" you probably mean quotes, but does not change answer - trim extra characters before parsing.

Comment: It seems that the quotes are automatically removed by that library (or peraphs by the API itself)